# How to Keep repository alive in MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Hi I am looking for a way on keeping a repository initialised throughout the application lifetime. At the moment I am initialising each repository on every controller. So its always going to the database on every new controller and if the result set is large, this slows the app down

```
    public Controller()
        : this(new someRepository()
    {
        ...........
    }

    public Controller(IRepository IRepository , )
    {
        ....
    }
```

I am not using Dependency Injection, but some sample code or a direction to a site would be useful.

Thanks

Comment: Be sure not to end up sharing the same entity framework context across requests.

Comment: While old it may be interesting to other readers. Using a static (either as real static, or dependency injection singleton object) is generally considered bad, especially with ORM Framework such as EntityFramework and can cause severe slowdown if the context is kept alive for too long (too long = longer than the actual request). That being said, your Repository constructor shouldn't do any heavy or time consuming tasks and should be very fast to instantiate a repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `static` variable that stores the repository instance.

```
public class SomeRepository
{
   private static SomeRepository _instance;
   public static SomeRepository Instance
   {
       get 
       {
           return _instance ?? (_instance = new SomeRepository());
       }
   }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public Controller()
        : this(SomeRepository.Instance)
    {
        ...........
    }

    public Controller(IRepository IRepository , )
    {
        ....
    }
```

Comment: So basically make the repository class a static clasS?

Comment: @user3428422 no, you can store an instance of your repository in a static variable. See  the edited answer for a sample.

Comment: OK that made sense but the repository method of when I get my data is a contract in a interface so I cant use Static

Comment: @user3428422 you don't need to make any method static, you have to store an instance of your repository in a static field and access it from there instead of creating an instance every time.

Comment: +0: Static (or any other flavor of application lifetime) is generally problematic in multithreaded contexts like ASP.Net - make sure your object is thread safe before going this route. Note if you use dependency injection container (like Unity, ninject,...) than it will likely have alternative to `static` by allowing to register instance of object/singleton.

Comment: Thanks both, I agree @AlexeiLevenkov, I have used ninject a bit, and will implement that once this phrase of project is over, when you say thread safe, what do you mean? i am not using any background threads or async operations as such, its not its a desktop app.. interesting concept! and thanks brz i was being stupid. it worked.

Comment: @user3428422 - yes, exactly - it is not desktop app - so all incoming requests will run in parallel...

Answer (score 2):

One good strategy is to use caching. Take a look at System.Web.Caching.Cache. First time you fetch your data you can write it in the cache and retrieve it from there on consecutive reads (assuming the data has not changed).

Comment: That sounds good but I guess I won't be able to use caching in a non web app project.. as my repositories are in a class library project

Comment: you should be cacheing the results that your repo calls return. the repo itself should not know or care that the results are being cached.

Comment: I agree with that and that's how I thought it should be like, but how do I pass the Cache object via a parameter into non controller class? Is this possible?

Comment: +1. Mindful caching of *results* is much better that making anything static in ASP.Net app, especially potentially non-thread safe classes like simple implementations of a repository.

Comment: @user3428422 - not sure what problem you have "pass Cache object via parameter"... If you need support ASP.Net and console/WPF/WinForms projects - abstract Cache with some interface and wrap both `Cache` classes to implement your interface.